# Can't wrap my head around MySQL statement

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

cache and main

In cache there are a lot of fields; in main a little less. A UNION is not going to work because of the unequal number of columns.

cache
client - file - target - many other columns

main
client - file - target - few other columns

From cache I would like all columns for which main.target LIKE '%string%', cache.client = main.client, cache.file = main.file

For these particular records, target, client and file are always the same in main and cache.

I just can't get my head around this, but then again MySQL never was my strongest point.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: A `UNION` will work fine, just name the columns explicitly (which you're meant to do anyway).

Comment: "From cache I would like all columns for which main.target LIKE '%string%', cache.client = main.client, cache.file = main.file" - SQL cannot filter columns like that: SQL is row (tuple)-oriented, not column (attribute) oriented.

Comment: We can't really help you further without seeing your `CREATE TABLE` statements and sample data - ideally please create a DBFiddle or SQLFiddle and link to it.

Comment: When you say all columns, do you mean all rows? Rows != columns.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments so far. I'm going to try Dai's suggestion above but I'm suddenly very much pressed for time at the moment. I promise to get back to you all this week.

Answer (score 0):

In the end combining the two SELECT statements with a UNION made things very complicated, for the simple reason there were countless other queries, some without UNION, that in the end all had to be processed by the same end routine presenting the results. As this was only a one-time query and time wasn't really an issue, in the end I just used SELECT on the two different tables and then combined the results by checking if a certain field was present. If not, the remaining results had to be fetched from the cache table; if so, the remaining results had to be fetched from the main table.

I actually wonder whether this solution is faster, slower or just as fast.

```
if (!isset($row['current']))
            {
                $field = $row['field'];
                $sqlcache = "SELECT * FROM " . $dbtable . " WHERE (client = '$sqlclient' AND file = '$sqlfile' AND field = '$field')";
                $resultcache = $conn->query($sqlcache);
                if (!$resultcache)
                {
                    die($conn->error);
                }
                $rowcache = $resultcache->fetch_assoc();
                $currenttarget = $rowcache['current'];
                $context = $rowcache['context'];
                $dirtysource = $rowcache['dirtysource'];
                $stringid = $rowcache['stringid'];
                $limit = $rowcache['maxlength'];
                $locked = $rowcache['locked'];
                $filei = $rowcache['filei'];
            }
            else
            {
                $currenttarget = $row['current'];
                $context = $row['context'];
                $dirtysource = $row['dirtysource'];
                $stringid = $row['stringid'];
                $limit = $row['maxlength'];
                $locked = $row['locked'];
                $filei = $row['filei'];
            }
```